# Notify admin (by email) if post added with specific tag

Tags: php, functions, tags, notifications

I have some specific functionality based on post's tags.

How can I send email to admin@blog.com when:
1) user add new post with specific tag (ex. 'tag1') 
OR
2) user edit his pending post and assign specific tag ('tag1')?

Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some simple code provided straight out of the WordPress codex.
If you are not familiar with the Codex, you should make time to do so.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

```
function my_project_updated_send_email( $post_id ) {

// If this is just a revision, don't send the email.
if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
    return;

// get the post data and check for tags here ...
$newpost = get_post( $post_id );
// Now you can do anything with the $newpost object you just created
// 
// End of your custom code

$post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
$post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
$subject = 'A post has been updated';

$message = "A post has been updated on your website:\n\n";
$message .= $post_title . ": " . $post_url;

// Send email to admin.
wp_mail( 'admin@example.com', $subject, $message );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_project_updated_send_email' );
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The problem here is that if I add/modify only tags of the post - than wordpress does not add a new revision, so your code wont work.

Comment: And it seems for me that revisions data does not include post's tag(s) information

Answer (score 0):

There are more action hooks related to saving and updating a post/page. So you may want to add_action for these as well and hook them to your function.

To get the tags when a post is saved, there is a section where I indicated you must put additional code. This would be something like a wp_get_post_tags( $post_id ) function call where you can then manipulate the data.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_tags

Again, you should reallu explore the codex as all of the action hooks and functions are explained there.